# How can we remove undesirable suggestions from Yahoo Search Auto-complete for our business?

Tags: seo, local-seo, suggestions

When one of my clients business names is typed into the Yahoo search bar, the auto complete has some unusual results:

When typing in the business name followed by the the area it shows the auto complete option of the `business name + location + Bankruptcy`. The company has never filed for bankruptcy, and no bankruptcy-related results come up for any pages where the business name is actually mentioned. It is also not written anywhere in text or titles on their website.

Is there a way to find out why this auto-complete option is coming up and how to make a change to fix it?

Comment: Doesn't do it on my Bing or Google. Caching can occur with IP and by logging into a MS service. Make sure you try cookieless in Chrome for example by doing CTRL+N to fire up incognito.

Answer (score 1):

If the auto complete is being done by your browser then your end clients won't be seeing it at all and it will be to do with a search done from the computer in question. If it is being done through the suggested search terms for Yahoo then there is no way to do that as the recommended search terms is algorithmically done and so there is no way to manually change the details.